# how do I load balance java threads on multiple tomcat web servers?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, load-balancing

My web application is running on **3 tomcat** servers(let's say tom1, tom2, tom3); And, I Am using **nginx** for session *load balancing*.

Assume, the user has launched a job thread (let's say job1) on tom1 and it will be completed in 2 days.

Suppose if `tom1` is down then `job1` should be continued on another server.
How do I load balance java threads on multiple tomcat web servers?

Comment: That’s not load balancing, that’s failover.  https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-clustering. I'm also not a huge fan of long running processes on app servers; too many things can go wrong. It's better to spin up another process that can handle that long running process or use a grid solution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about grid solution

Comment: Distributed processing through something like Hadoop, or Oracle Grid Server. It allows you to schedule, execute, and parallelize workloads across several machines. The idea is that you’re separating your OLTP (online transaction processing) from analytical or batch processing allowing you to achieve better scalability and throughput.